# Authentication with Passport Session on Android

Tags: android, node.js, session, authentication, express

I have a web app currently running with NodeJS and Express, where I authenticate the users using Passport sessions, and it works perfectly. Here is the overview of what I do:

```
app.use(session({
    secret : 'hidden of course :)',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/****** Passport functions ******/
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.idUser);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    db.user.findOne( { where : { idUser : id } }).then(function (user, err) {
        done(null, user);
    });
});

//Facebook
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    //Information stored on config/auth.js
    clientID: *******,
    clientSecret: ******,
    callbackURL: *******,
    profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'displayName', 'name', 'gender', 'picture.type(large)'] 

}, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //Using next tick to take advantage of async properties
    process.nextTick(function () {
        db.user.findOne( { where : { idUser : profile.id } }).then(function (user, err) {
            if(err) {
                return done(err);
            } 
            if(user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                // Check whether the email is undefined or valid
                var emailTemp = '';
                if(profile.emails && profile.emails[0] && profile.emails[0].value) {
                    emailTemp = profile.emails[0].value;
                } else {
                    emailTemp = '';
                }

                var picture = '';
                if(profile.photos && profile.photos[0] && profile.photos[0].value) {
                    picture = profile.photos[0].value;
                } else {
                    picture = '/img/profile.png';
                }

                var sexFb = '';
                if(profile.gender) {
                    sexFb = profile.gender;
                } else {
                    sexFb = '';
                }

                // Create the user
                db.user.create({
                    idUser : profile.id,
                    token : accessToken,
                    picture : picture,
                    nameUser : profile.displayName,
                    email : emailTemp,
                    sex : sexFb
                }).then(function () {
                    db.user.findOne( { where : { idUser : profile.id } }).then(function (user, err) {
                        if(user) {
                            return done(null, user);
                        } else {
                            return done(err);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

/* FACEBOOK STRATEGY */
// Redirect the user to Facebook for authentication.  When complete,
// Facebook will redirect the user back to the application at
//     /auth/facebook/callback//
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : ['email']}));
/* FACEBOOK STRATEGY */
// Facebook will redirect the user to this URL after approval.  Finish the
// authentication process by attempting to obtain an access token.  If
// access was granted, the user will be logged in.  Otherwise,
// authentication has failed.

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function (req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        res.redirect('../../app.html');
});
```

Now, I'm building our Android App and I need to authenticate our users, preferably using the backend I already built for the web version. I was [checking some questions on SO like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486397/passport-login-and-persisting-session) and I understood a lot of what I would have to do.

Currently my clients stay logged in through the cookie that Express-session handles, saving the user's id on the req.user, so that I can run queries like on this example:

```
app.put('/profile', function (req, res) {
    //Updates the profile information of the user
    db.user.update({
        nameUser : req.body.nameUser
    }, {
        where : {
            idUser : req.user.idUser
        }
    }).then(function (user) {
        res.json({ yes : "yes" });
    });
});
```

**So my questions:**

1. Can I authenticate my users using the same strategy as the one I currently have? If not, what would I have to change to be able to authenticate my users on Android?
2. Once they are authenticated, how can I set the req.user from Android (through HTTP request or whatever mean) to correctly perform the tasks on the backend (since all my requests are based on req.user)? I assume Android doesn't keep cookies like browsers do, so how would Passport Sessions know which user is calling the API?
3. I currently use Retrofit2 on my Android app to interact with the API, is it able to perform the actions necessary for this task?

Sorry for the long post, added a good chunk of code just to be on the safe side, if you guys have any questions or need any explanation please let me know!

Comment: Hi! Did you solve this?

Comment: @Nux yes, I sent the auth token for my android app and used it on the http requests to authenticate the users. it's been awhile since I had this problem so thats the TLDR can't really remember much else answer.