# sending the regenerated session-id back to user agent after login with user object in nodejs

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js, setcookie, express-session

I am re-generating the `session-id` after the user logs-in,the new session id gets generated and i am also saving that session-id in mongodb but the issue is how do i send the re-generated session-id back to the user-agent(browser) with the user object.
`I have already tried:`

```
res.cookie('sessionId',req.session);
res.json(user);
```

I am re-generating session-d like this:

```
let session = req.session;
console.log("printing old session");
console.log(req.sessionID);

req.session.regenerate(function(err) {

if (err)     console.log(err);
else{
console.log("printing new session");
console.log(req.sessionID);

let prev_session = session;
//Copying Prev Session Data to current session.
for (let i in prev_session) {

req.session[i] = prev_session[i];

}
req.session.save();

}
})
```

the above code returns the user object with session-id in header as :

```
set-cookie: sessionId=j%3A%7B%22cookie%22%3A%7B%22originalMaxAge%22%3A86400000%2C%22
expires%22%3A%222018-07-10T06%3A16%3A16.703Z%22%2C%22secure%22%3Afalse%2C%22httpOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22
path%22%3A%22%2F%22%7D%2C%22_csrfSecret%22%3A%22fYvLa6exta46VA%3D%3D%22%2C%22passport%22%3A%7B%22
user%22%3A%225b1fcebb293e95fc28cafc97%22%7D%7D; Path=
```

with this previous sessionid :

```
set-cookie: sessionId=s%3AZ4HI3m3LzPcxRlp8HVEb4YzIGq3FuZbC.07kibg%2FguTNBTPlO5%2BTfHSkDh7GcQEzenlSqODetvb8; 
Path=/; Expires=Tue, 10 Jul 2018 06:16:29 GMT; HttpOnly
```

still i am unable to see the updated session-id in session cookie of my chrome browser

My backend is powered by express and passport.

can anyone please help me in this...i have already spend a lot in browsing this issue and have'nt got any working solution.

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: when you `req.session[i] = prev_session[i];`, doesn't it copies the session id as well? Can you put a `console.log("::"+prev_session[i])` inside forloop  and paste the output? If its prints object, please JSON.stringify it before printing.

Comment: ::{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":86399999,"expires":"2018-07-10T09:04:31.824Z","sec
ure":false,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"_csrfSecret":"6Yml234gs6SA==","passpor
t":{"user":"5b1fc23423423423497"}}  ...i tried printing the whole` prev_session` and this is the result i got.. @eduPeeth

Comment: are you using `cookie-parser`?

Comment: yes @DushyantBangal

Comment: is there any way like whenever and where-ever req.login() is getting called just change the the session id after the function execution or credential check.. does passport provides this functionality? @DushyantBangal

Comment: @PrabhatMishra, `req.login` will only be called in your login API (maybe in signup as well). You can do what you want in the `req.login` callback.

Comment: @PrabhatMishra however, I would recommend you just use `express-session` or some middleware that manages and stores these sessions properly. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486397/passport-login-and-persisting-session

Comment: however middleware will be invoked when the user is redirected to `/login` and before the authentication so i think there is no chance of building middleware but we can build something that gets called after the `req.login()` is completed or may be customizing the req.login()...i don't know how :( @DushyantBangal

Comment: @PrabhatMishra, no, just look at how `passport` and `express-session` can be used together. They handle it, you dont need to go on generating the sessions everytime. There are lots of tutorials out there. See this: https://www.airpair.com/express/posts/expressjs-and-passportjs-sessions-deep-dive

Comment: @DushyantBangal yeah i am using `passport and express-session` for storing the session and initializing it with session id and csrf token then once the user logs-in i am regenerating the session the sssion gets stored in mongodb and then once the user logs-out i destroy the current session. so now i just want something or may be i feel the need to overwrite the `req.login()`  method of passport.js so it re-generates the session id once the user calls  `req.login()`

Comment: But thats what happens with `express-session`! A new session is generated on login. Maybe I'm not getting your point, you should put another question on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why are have `sessionId`, `req.sessionID`, `req.session` in your code, because all of them are different things.

Using `cookie-parser`:

**Write cookie:**

```
res.cookie('myCookieName',myValue)
```

**Read cookie:**

```
req.cookies.myCookieName
```

If your new regenerated session ID is in `req.sessionID` then use that while setting the cookie and not `req.session`

I have a basic example that should guide you for your implementation:

```
const express = require('express'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();

var i =0;
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{ 

    console.log("Previous cookie: ",req.cookies.sessionId);
    res.cookie('sessionId',{i:++i, maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
    res.send('Hello World!')});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

This will print the cookie sent in the request, and then send back a new one. In every request, you will see a different number printed on the node console.

Comment: `sessionId` is name of the cookie ,`req.sessionID` returns the current session id and `req.session` returns the current session object ,these i need to use so that i can replicate the data such as user object and xsrf token ...

Comment: Yes, but you were setting `req.session` as the cookie value, which is what confused me. Anyways, if those are handled by passport, then you'll get those. This is how you can set the cookie.